# For loops in ejs

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs, backend

I have a array containing some html content like this.

```
const articleArray=['<p>first text</p>\r\n','<p>second text></p>\r\n','<p>third text</p>\r\n']
```

I need to render this in an ejs file through a get request

```
request.render('viewArticles',{array : articleArray})
```

where 'viewArticles' is an ejs file. I have used the middleware to set the view engine as ejs.
This is the code in ejs

```
<% for(arr in array) {%>
    arr
<% } %>
```

I am not able to render any html. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'<%- %>' this is help to print html code as it is.

- <% 'Scriptlet' tag, for control-flow, no output
- <%_ ‘Whitespace Slurping’ Scriptlet tag, strips all whitespace before it
- <%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
- <%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template
- <%# Comment tag, no execution, no output
- <%% Outputs a literal '<%'
- %> Plain ending tag
- -%> Trim-mode ('newline slurp') tag, trims following newline
- _%> ‘Whitespace Slurping’ ending tag, removes all whitespace after it

  for refrence  please click visit this site [EJS](https://ejs.co/)

  `<% array.forEach(function(item) {%>
      <%-item%>
  <% }) %>`

Comment: Please explain. A code only answer is very low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<% array.forEach(function(item,index){ %>
        <%= item %> 
    <% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how to do what you want exactly , but take a look at this:

First, instead of you creating an array of HTML elements, how about you create an array of objects, like so :

```js
const articles = [{text: "first text"} , {text: "second text"}, {text: "third text"}];
```

this way you just have to write the HTML once, and I am fairly new to programming but I don't see a scenario where you would get a response in HTML, usually you query a database for data or from a JSON file... and assuming the array is actually getting passed to the .ejs file, lets iterate though it,

```js
<% for(let a of articles){ %>

    <p> <%= a.text %> </p> 
    </br>

<% } %>
```

If the array is **NOT** getting passed, check for these in your code :

```js
// If you installed 
..."dependencies" : {
     "ejs": "x.x.x", 
} //Check the package.json file
```

```js
// If you imported correctly
import ejs = require("ejs");

// If you specified the views path
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

// And the views engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

```js
// And your route
request.render('viewArticles',{ articles : articles }) // Check if the file name is correct, I get this wrong many times
```

Comment: The array is fetched from a database stored in html.I used ckeditor for storing textarea forms.